# Calculate the % difference of two columns in pivot table

Tags: python, pivot-table, average

I have two columns on pivot table and I would like to find the %difference.

```
table['% average_change'] = ["Price per carat, 2015" / "Price per carat, 2019"]
print(table)
average_count = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["color", "carat"],values=["Price per carat","Year"],columns=["Year"])
print(average_count)
average_count = pd.pivot_table(df,index=["color", "carat"],values=["Price per carat","Year"],columns=["Year"])
print(average_count)
                  Price per carat              
Year                         2015          2019
color carat                                    
DI1   0.3 - 0.39      1356.500000           NaN
      0.50 - 0.69     1983.500000           NaN
      0.70 - 0.79     2415.000000           NaN
      0.90 - 0.99     2848.000000           NaN
      1.00 - 1.24     3279.555556   3361.000000
      1.25 - 1.49     4209.333333           NaN
      1.50 - 1.99     3609.333333           NaN
      2.00 - 2.99     4784.000000           NaN
      3.00 - 3.99     4695.000000           NaN
DIF   0.23 - 0.29     3307.000000           NaN
      0.3 - 0.39      4816.687500   2553.555556
      0.4 - 0.44              NaN   3365.500000
      0.45 - 0.49     4977.000000           NaN
      0.50 - 0.69     7486.333333           NaN
      0.70 - 0.79     7181.000000   5455.000000
      0.80 - 0.89     9024.000000           NaN
      0.90 - 0.99    10202.000000           NaN
      1.00 - 1.24    15624.464286   9510.333333
      1.50 - 1.99             NaN  15730.000000
      2.00 - 2.99             NaN  21285.000000
      3.00 - 3.99             NaN  86900.000000
DSI1  0.18 - 0.22             NaN   1519.000000
      0.23 - 0.29     2214.750000   1300.000000
      0.3 - 0.39      2070.844860   1829.000000
      0.4 - 0.44      2097.825871           NaN
      0.45 - 0.49     2271.428571           NaN
      0.50 - 0.69     3039.090024   2656.857143
      0.70 - 0.79     3922.832031   3559.400000
      0.80 - 0.89     4288.363636           NaN
      0.90 - 0.99     4829.680233           NaN
...                           ...           ...
MVS2  1.25 - 1.49             NaN   3089.333333
      2.00 - 2.99             NaN   4296.000000
      3.00 - 3.99             NaN   6187.000000
MVVS1 1.00 - 1.24             NaN   2553.500000
      1.25 - 1.49             NaN   3277.000000
      1.50 - 1.99             NaN   3896.000000
      2.00 - 2.99             NaN   5618.500000
      3.00 - 3.99             NaN   9570.000000
MVVS2 1.00 - 1.24             NaN   3251.000000
      1.25 - 1.49             NaN   3174.500000
      1.50 - 1.99             NaN   3702.500000
      2.00 - 2.99             NaN   5379.500000
      3.00 - 3.99             NaN   5329.000000
      5.00 - 5.99             NaN   9614.000000
NSI1  2.00 - 2.99             NaN   2574.000000
NVS1  1.00 - 1.24             NaN   2926.000000
      2.00 - 2.99             NaN   4108.666667
      3.00 - 3.99             NaN   5141.666667
      4.00 - 4.99             NaN   4950.000000
NVS2  1.50 - 1.99             NaN   3520.000000
      2.00 - 2.99             NaN   4114.000000
      4.00 - 4.99             NaN   6264.000000
NVVS1 1.50 - 1.99             NaN   3643.000000
      2.00 - 2.99             NaN   5033.666667
      3.00 - 3.99             NaN   6412.000000
NVVS2 1.00 - 1.24             NaN   3303.250000
      1.25 - 1.49             NaN   3103.000000
      1.50 - 1.99             NaN   3388.000000
      2.00 - 2.99             NaN   4643.000000
      3.00 - 3.99             NaN   6007.750000

[788 rows x 2 columns]
count
average_count.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 788 entries, (DI1, 0.3 - 0.39) to (NVVS2, 3.00 - 3.99)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
(Price per carat, 2015)    626 non-null float64
(Price per carat, 2019)    457 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 14.8+ KB
age_count
average_count['% average_change'] = ["Price per carat, 2015" / "Price per carat, 2019"]
print(average_count)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-55289a2a7674> in <module>
----> 1 average_count['% average_change'] = ["Price per carat, 2015" / "Price per carat, 2019"]
      2 print(average_count)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'
```

Comment: When you use `["Price per carat, 2015" / "Price per carat, 2019"]` are you intending to be referencing certain columns in your table?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying reference the price of the diamonds per carat in 2015 which is the first column and the price per carat in 2019 which is the second column.

Comment: Right. You've specified the column names but haven't specified where they are, e.g. a dataframe

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for the reply, but I am not too sure how to specify where they are, do you think you can guide me?

Comment: Sure. [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html#selection) are a great place to start